# r Sum by Group of Same Name

Tags: r

Is there any way to sum this data without a loop in r?
There is not an NA or blank in the first row.
It is a list of sequential data.

Before:

```
Column 1  Column 2
FLOWING 
DOWNTIME  1,922
FLOWING   23
FLOWING   8
FLOWING   23
FLOWING   26
DOWNTIME  36
FLOWING   1
FLOWING   8
DOWNTIME  12
FLOWING   0
FLOWING   3
FLOWING   13
DOWNTIME  2
FLOWING   10
FLOWING   12
FLOWING   30
DOWNTIME  24
DOWNTIME  1
```

After:

```
Column 1  Column 2
FLOWING 
DOWNTIME  1,922
FLOWING   80
DOWNTIME  36
FLOWING   9
DOWNTIME  12
FLOWING   16
DOWNTIME  2
FLOWING   52
DOWNTIME  25
```

Comment: Any reason of excluding the 36 value against DOWNTIME (7th row) ? Thanks

Comment: no it was a mistake on my part it has been added back in

Comment: can you show us the results of running `str()` (or `dput()`) on your data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are `,` in the 'Column2' which would make it a `character` class.  So we remove the `,` convert it to `numeric` and get the `sum` after grouping by run-length-id of 'Column1' (`rleid` from `data.table`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df1 %>%
    mutate(Column2 = as.numeric(str_remove(Column2, ","))) %>%
    group_by(grp = rleid(Column1)) %>% 
    summarise(Column1 = first(Column1), 
              Column2 = sum(Column2)) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    select(-grp)
```

---

Or using `data.table` methods

```
setDT(df1)[, .(Column1 = first(Column1), 
      Column2 = sum(as.numeric(sub(",", "", Column2)))), .(grp = rleid(Column1))]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Column1 = c("FLOWING", "DOWNTIME", "FLOWING", 
 "FLOWING", "FLOWING", "FLOWING", "DOWNTIME", "FLOWING", "FLOWING", 
 "DOWNTIME", "FLOWING", "FLOWING", "FLOWING", "DOWNTIME", "FLOWING", 
 "FLOWING", "FLOWING", "DOWNTIME", "DOWNTIME"), Column2 = c("", 
 "1,922", "23", "8", "23", "26", "36", "1", "8", "12", "0", "3", 
 "13", "2", "10", "12", "30", "24", "1")), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c(NA, -19L))
```